# closed set contained in the rationals between $0$ and $1$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E= [0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Construct a closed set contained in $E$, call it $F$ such that we have have $m_*(E \setminus F)<\epsilon$ where $m_*$ is exterior measure not Lebesgue measure. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $E \setminus F = [0, 1] \setminus \mathbb Q \setminus F$ is Lebesgue measurable, so it makes no difference if we use exterior or Lebesgue measure. Also if for any $\epsilon > 0$, $m_*(X) < \epsilon$, then just $m_*(X) = 0$.

There is no such set: as $F$ is closed, $(0, 1) \setminus F$ is open, also $\frac{1}{2} \in (0, 1) \setminus F$, so for some $\epsilon$, $\left( \frac{1}{2} - \varepsilon; \frac{1}{2} + \epsilon\right) \cap F = \varnothing$. So we have $\left( \frac{1}{2} - \epsilon; \frac{1}{2} + \epsilon\right) \setminus \mathbb Q \subset E \setminus F$. And as $m_*(\left( \frac{1}{2} - \epsilon; \frac{1}{2} + \epsilon\right) \setminus \mathbb Q) = 2\epsilon$, $m_*(E \setminus F) \geqslant 2\epsilon$.

If you switch order of quantifiers - ie $\forall \epsilon \exists F\, m_*(E \setminus F) < \epsilon$, it's standard construction: let $q_m$ be some enumeration of rationals in $[0, 1]$ and let $F = [0, 1] \setminus \bigcup\limits_{m=1}^\infty (q_m - \epsilon\cdot 2^{-m - 1}; q_m + \epsilon\cdot 2^{-m - 1})$.

Comment: So there does not exists a closed set inside $E$ such that measure of $E$ minus $F$ is less than epsilon? Look at problem 4 please http://web.csulb.edu/~wmurray/comps/Real20s.pdf

Comment: It's what is the second part of my answer is about - we construct different $F$s for different $\epsilon$s. It's not the same as constructing one $F$ for all $\epsilon$.

Comment: Oh yes the construction of $F$ is dependent on the given epsilon correct? Yes that I understand!

Comment: I am sorry, I posed the question incorrect! I did mean to start with a given epsilon then construct $F$, thanks!@

Comment: Yes, it is dependent. Note that $F$ in my construction explicitly depends on $\epsilon$.

Comment: quick question, is your subscript in the $\bigcup$ where you define $F$ supposed to be from $m=1$ to $\infty$? not $i=1$?

Comment: Yes, it is. Fixed now.